# How can I define a HashMap with multiple value types in Java?

Tags: java, hashmap

My current HashMap has the following structure, which is working fine for me.

```java
Map<String, List<MyClass>> data = new HashMap<String, List<MyClass>>() {{
   put("correct", new ArrayList<MyClass>());
   put("incorrect", new ArrayList<MyClass>());
}}
```

Nevertheless I want to add a string to the same HashMap. I already tried the following, but it leads to an error when I want to add new elements to the ArrayList's.

```java
Map<String, Object> data = new HashMap<String, Object>() {{
   put("correct", new ArrayList<MyClass>());
   put("incorrect", new ArrayList<MyClass>());
   put("filestring", new String());
}}
```

The error:

```
class java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to class java.util.Set (java.util.ArrayList and java.util.Set are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
```

The way I try to add new elements to the ArrayList's:

```
((Set<List<MyClass>>) data.get("correct")).add((List<MyClass>) new MyClass());
```

Does anybody know how I can achieve the above? I highly appreciate any kind of help, cheers!

Comment: [Do not use double-brace initialization.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1958636/what-is-double-brace-initialization-in-java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you store for the key "correct" is `new ArrayList<MyClass>()`:

```
   put("correct", new ArrayList<MyClass>());
```

But on reading it back you try to cast it into a `(Set<List<MyClass>>)` which will not work.

In a similar way later on you try the cast `(List<MyClass>) new MyClass()` which will also fail.

To add a new element you need to write

```
((List<MyClass>) data.get("correct")).add(new MyClass());
```

Comment: Thanks, that solved my problem. Never trust an IDE! It suggested to use `(Set<List<MyClass>>)`